# PHP base64 convert to jpg file is large

Tags: php, base64, crop

I open one file with 70kb :

`$img = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($img));`

If I save this code via below code, image saved with 1.5mb size!

```
$file = fopen('new.jpg', "wb");
$data = explode(',', $img);
fwrite($file, base64_decode($data[1]));
fclose($file);
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: Why encode and decode? base64_encode() might increase the file size by 33% https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877353/after-encoding-data-size-is-increasing. Why not just `fwrite` the binary data?

Comment: Apart from that this doesn’t appear to make much sense to begin with, as already mentioned - have you checked what the resulting file actually contained? Can you open it as an image in an image editor? If not, what do you see when you open it with a text or hex editor?